# Neo4j, NoMethodError: undefined method 'outgoing' for

Tags: ruby, neo4j, neo4j.rb

I have a small Neo4j database with two nodes: `Author` and `Book`. The relationship is that one or more authors authored books.
From the rails console I am loading an `Author` node and I am getting a result

```
a = Neo4j::Node.load(36) 
=> #<Author name: "Levi">
```

The next one is giving me and error

```
a.outgoing(:BOOKS)
NoMethodError: undefined method `outgoing' for #<Author name: "Levi">
    from /Users/levidamian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activemodel-4.1.8/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):7
```

What is wrong here?

EDIT:

Neo4j gems:

```
neo4j (4.1.1)
neo4j-core (4.0.1, 4.0.0)
neo4j-cypher (1.0.4)
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'neo4j' 
gem 'neo4j-cypher'
gem 'thin'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'spring', group: :development
group :production do 
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. What gems and versions of those gems are you using?

Comment: neo4j (4.1.1)
neo4j-core (4.0.1, 4.0.0)
neo4j-cypher (1.0.4)

Comment: neo4j (4.1.1)
neo4j-core (4.0.1, 4.0.0)
neo4j-cypher (1.0.4)

Comment: gem 'neo4j'
gem 'neo4j-cypher'
gem 'thin'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'spring', group: :development
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

Comment: Where did you find a reference to `neo4j-cypher`? Is it linked somewhere? It shouldn't be used, it contains early code that was eventually made part of `neo4j-core`.

Comment: That actually looks like that could be how the previous version of the neo4j gems worked before 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.outgoing(:BOOKS)` looks like a method from the `neo4j-cypher` gem, which was never part of the released versions of Neo4j or Neo4j-core. You should remove this gem from your project and if you came across a resource somewhere telling you to use it, let them know that they have outdated information.

If you're using Neo4j::ActiveNode and models, see the documentation at https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki. If you just want basic Neo4j connectivity and methods, use Neo4j-core and see https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-core.

Comment: Thank you for advise. I am (very) new to Neo4j and don't have any experience. I removed the neo4j-cypher gem as indicated. Both my model classes Author and Book contains the line include Neo4j::ActiveNode which means I am using ActiveNode. What I am trying to solve here is this problem: A book may have one or many authors. I need a method in the books_controller.rb (I am using RoR) having a query to be executed like this: start n=node(4) match n<-[:BOOKS]-(m) return n,m; which runs ok in the neo4j-shell returning the two authors the book (node:4) has and I need to get their names from result.

Comment: Read through the Neo4j.rb's docs, also check out the [launch screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDjbqRL9HcM) for some basics. If you need more help, you can mark this question as answered and start a new one.

Comment: I've posted a bunch of questions @levid over the past few months. Hope they're useful to you